# CSS - TBody e TR com medidas diferentes

Tags: css, css3

Como faço para meu TBody ter 100% de altura e minha TR ter n pixel de tamanho? ocorre que quando tenho apenas uma linha, a linha fica com 100%, correspondente ao TBody, e gostaria que ela ficasse fininha! Deu pra entender?

Comment: 100% de que? Altura? Largura?

Comment: Height! foi mal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o que você precisa é trabalhar com a propriedade `position` dos elementos. Por exemplo, considerando que a tabela estará dentro de uma `div` de 500px x 500px:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #EfEfEf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Stack Overflow em Português</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Para que a tabela preencha o espaço da `div`, basta adicionar `position: absolute` junto com `width: 100%` e `height: 100%`. Veja:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #EfEfEf;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #CC0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Stack Overflow em Português</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Perceba que a tabela preencheu todo o espaço, mas o `tbody` e o `tr` o acompanharam. Fazendo algo semelhante com o `tbody`:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  
  background: #EfEfEf;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background: #CC0000;
}

table tbody {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  background: green;
}

table tbody tr {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Stack Overflow em Português</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Vestibulum tortor nunc, lobortis efficitur eleifend nec, tristique dictum erat</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Perceba que ao definir também o `tbody` com `position: absolute` e as dimensões em `width` e `height`, o corpo da tabela passa a preencher todo o espaço da `div`, mas as linhas definidas por `tr` continuam no tamanho padrão.

Answer (score -1):

No seu elemento: `<tr>`, adicione o estilo:

```
line-height: 4px;
```

npx, na verdade, defina o tamanho que você quiser.

Pode também alterar o padding e margin da tr. E se estiver usando algum estilo pronto, tipo: bootstrap, vai ter que dar uma olhada nos estilos das tds, inclusive.